# redirecting sub-sub pages to another website with the same structure

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect

we recently took over a domain to split one website into two. The website with automatically generated urls was moved to another domain, but there are still multiple users who have the previously generated links. Because of that we had to set up a redirect, that technically worked fine.

Redirect 302 /base1 https://newdomain/base1

As a result we get:
https://olddomain/base1/test1 -> https://newdomain/base1/test1

and it's just what we're trying to accomplish, so all sounds great so far. Unfortunately a new issue arose as apparently now we have to achieve the following:

https://olddomain/base1 -> https://olddomain/
and then the rest should work just as it does at the moment. I can't quite figure out how to get this redirect in place.

E: To keep it more readable. I updated as per @anubhava answer to the following:

```
RewriteRule ^base1/?$ / [L,NC,R=302]

RewriteRule ^base1(/.*)?$ https://newdomain/$0 [L,NC,NE,R=302]

Redirect 302 /base1 https://newdomain/base1
```

I'm trying to achieve the following result:

```
olddomain/base1 -> olddomain
olddomain/base1/url1 -> newdomain/base1/url1
olddomain/base1/url1/url2 -> newdomain/base1/url1/url2
```

Thanks,
S.

Answer (score 0):

You can add another rule before your existing rule but must use `mod_rewrite` rule for this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^base1/?$ / [L,NC,R=302]

RewriteRule ^base1(/.*)?$ https://newdomain/$0 [L,NC,NE,R=302]
```

Test it after clearing your browser cache or in a different browser.

Comment: I checked it, but it doesn't work (also, was it meant to be  
RewriteRule ^base1/?$ https://olddomain/ [L,NC,R=302] instead?)

Never mind which version I try out, the https://olddomain/base1 still goes to https://newdomain/base1 and it should be going to https://olddomain instead. Just to confirm - tested with cleared cache.

Comment: Ok I have updated the 1st rule. If you keep these rules before all other rules and completely clear browser cache then there is no reason why it cannot work.

Comment: It still doesn't work. I checked in a different browser and flushed the dns.

RewriteRule ^base1/?$ / [L,NC,R=302]

RewriteRule ^base1(/.*)?$ https://newdomain/$0 [L,NC,NE,R=302]

Redirect 302 /base1 https://newdomain/base1

oldomain/base1 still goes to newdomain/base1, instead of just going to olddomain

Comment: Change first rule to `RewriteRule ^base1/?$ / [L,NC,R=307]` and test again in Chrome dev tool to make sure if you get http status code `307` or not.